# Save CSVs as hyper file

Tags: csv, geospatial, tableau

I have three separate CSV files (Points.csv, PointsSynonym.csv, and LocalDataPoints.csv). I made these files after extracting data from shape files and .gpkg files.

I would like to save them all a single hyperfile. Is it possible to achieve this directly in the Tableau's interface? I tried using HyperAPI, but it throws errors. It there a more direct way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show what did you try and what kind of errors did you receive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681187/hyperexception-too-few-columns-in-input-file?noredirect=1#comment121381590_68681187 @Übermensch